# SSH tunneling in PhpStorm like putty

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, ssh-tunnel

I recently switched to PhpStorm IDE.

Since PhpStorm already has an SSH terminal, I would like to drop putty and use everything in PhpStorm.

But even after hours of trying I was not able to setup a tunnel like in putty for windows.

> For example I want to tunnel port `3306` on the server to `3307` on my
>   pc. But I have much more ports to tunnel.

Can anyone help me with this?

Any help would be appreciated.